# Managing constantly-changing JNLP dependencies?

Tags: java, ivy, jnlp, dependency-management

We use JNLP to deploy our Swing application to all of our users. With JNLP, you have to reference specific names/versions of any JAR dependencies, such as `widget-lib-1.4.7.jar`.

We have just introduced a new project that will compile as a reusable JAR, but that will be changing rapidly (every few days or so), and so the version number will change frequently. Our Swing app will depend on this new project once its completed.

Unless we change our setup, we'll have to update the JNLP and republish it every time we publish a new version of this new dependency, which, like I said, will be very frequent.

Is there any way to call Ivy from inside a JNLP, or some way of telling the JNLP to include the contents of a directory (and then have a separate process that always makes sure the latest version of the JAR is in that directory), or something we can do so that we don't have to constantly change the JNLP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you hosting a static JNLP file? Could you replace that with a JSP or Velocity template?

Comment: It's an HTML link to our JNLP file - can you elaborate on what you meant by a JSP template? Thanks (+1)!

Answer (score 1):

If your JNLP is updated frequently (or needs any other per-user parameters, like upload keys), don't use a static file. Instead, create a template JNLP file with JSP, Velocity, Freemarker, or a similar template engine and fill in the JNLP's fields dynamically, such as from a database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this addresses your need, but you could use a second .jnlp for your frequently changing library.  Your main application's .jnlp would refer to that .jnlp with an `<extension>` element.

Your main application's .jnlp would contain this:

```
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="MyApp.jar" main="true"/>
        <extension name="WidgetLib" href="WidgetLib.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
```

And WidgetLib.jnlp would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp href="WidgetLib.jnlp"
      version="1.4.7"
      codebase="http://www.company.com/myapp/">

    <information>
        <title>Widget Library</title>
        <vendor>My Company</vendor>
        <description>Latest version of Widget Library</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>

    <resources>
        <jar href="widget-lib-1.4.7.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```